# Do I need to register my own created .js and .css files

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, user-registration, css

I have several .js and .css files which I created for my theme. (*not a child theme*)

Styles and scripts are at the moment hard-coded in the head and work as wished. Now I read a lot about register and enqueue and move to footer.
(I am also aware that loading scripts into the footer is for better page loading.)

My question:

- Do I need to first register and then enqueue them both (.js and .css)
- If yes, why also the need to register them

An example which imho could work, or?

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'our_theme_scripts_styles' );
function the_theme_scripts_styles() {
    // extra stylesheet (In parent theme)
    wp_register_style( 'my-style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/my-style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/my-style.css' );

    // move script(s) into footer (In parent theme)
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/my-script.js', array(), false, true );  
    wp_enqueue_script(  'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/my-script.js', array(), false, true );
}
```

I am pretty new in the WP 'world' so it would be nice to find some answers for my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are registering the styles/scripts, then you will be setting all the parameters at that point. No need to pass them all again when enqueuing - by then you will only need to pass the handle.

If you are definitely only going to call your styles/scripts in one place, then you can skip the registration entirely. Instead, just enqueue, and pass all the params on the enqueue.

Comment: Both, .js and .css files will be used in 3 different custom post types and for 1 category. I assume the function as shown above is correctly? Could you enlight me a little more about the 'in one place' please?

Comment: In one place *in the code*.